# TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildAfatDebug

Tags: android, telegram

I want to Build [telegram](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram) apk and why I got This error:
`Build APK(s): Errors while building APK. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.`

```
:TMessagesProj:externalNativeBuildAfatDebug | 1m 6s 712ms
Execute build | 1m 6s 683ms
```

**My externalNativeBuild:**

```
  externalNativeBuild {
        ndkBuild {
            path "jni/Android.mk"
        }
    }
```

**Error Detail:**

```
org.gradle.internal.UncheckedException: Build command failed.
Error while executing process D:\Software\2-Programming\Android-Programming\android-ndk-r17b\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\TG\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\TG\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/TG/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\TG\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 D:/TG/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/debug/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libtmessages.29.so}
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_STL gnustl_static is deprecated and will be removed in the next release. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    
Android NDK: WARNING: Deprecated NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION value: 4.9. GCC is no longer supported and will be removed in the next release. See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/master/docs/ClangMigration.md.    
Android NDK: WARNING:D:\TG\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk:flac: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
Android NDK: WARNING: Unsupported source file extensions in D:\TG\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk for module flac    
Android NDK:   ./exoplayer/libFLAC/windows_unicode_filenames
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ggfan said: [Link](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/issues/561)

saw what you meant on my windows machine. It could not take the version string escapes. I just did:

```
-DVERSION=1.3.1
```

you could check what passed to command line compiler in your

```
%porject_dir%\TMessageProj\.externalNativeBuild\ndkBuild\arm64Debug\arm64-v8a\android_gradle_build.json
```

( for other arch types, go to its equivalent dir )

Then the next thing is posix_memalign() function. NDK platform 16 did not export the function, so out of the luck to build. Looks like 17 have it exported so if you change to android-17 for

```
"APP_PLATFORM:=android-17"
```

( and I do not know why linux build was ok the other day though: this thing could not be OS dependent ).

I think you could observe this with

```
ndk-bundle>toolchains\aarch64-linux-android-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\aarch64-linux-android\bin\nm.exe   platforms\android-17\arch-arm\usr\lib\libc.so
```

android-16 libc does not have it exported.

When building for 64 bit cpu architectures ( arm64, x86_64), it is ok because 64 bit was added much later ( android-21 I think ) and ndk-build would switch to android-21 automatically even you specify to use android-16

You Can Check this link too: [Link](https://github.com/grishka/libtgvoip/issues/8)